# Is there a way to change voice in pyttsx3 (python 3.10.4 x64)?

Tags: python, list, indexing, pyttsx3

```
import pyttsx3

engine = pyttsx3.init()

voices = engine.getProperty('voices')

engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id )

engine.say('I\'m a little teapot...')

engine.runAndWait()
```

When I try run this code I get this error message;

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\Username\Desktop\Python\Project 1\main.py", line 7, in 
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id )
IndexError: list index out of range

But when I set voices id 1 to 0, program runs without error.
How can i change speaker voice female to male?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably solve it by installing more voices on your OS. It seems you either have only one voice installed or PyTTSX3 doesn't see more than one for some reason and you must find why. First check how many voices tts.getProperty("voices") returns. Then what you actually have on your system.

You should not use statically defined indices to pick a voice anyway. Define a list of voices you want and fallback to getProperty("voices")[0] if there is none of your chosen voices available.

Ow, and BTW, what engine are you actually using. You might be using an TTS engine or engine host that has only one voice but have more than one engine available. E.g. Windows now supports SAPI5 (you can even install SAPI4 if needed) and Windows One Core, You should be able to pick one by passing some args to init(). Linux can also host multiple engines via speech-dispatcher and so on.

Sorry I cannot help more specifically, but I used old PyTTSX which was good but buggy as hell, then I wrote my own TTS connector to avoid such nonsense like the TTS loop interfering with GUI main loop. So here is what might be happening.

Comment: If you do not detect problems on your system. Give me some more info, like what OS are you on, which API and so on. I'll install PyTTSX3 then and see whether there is a bug detecting all voices or something like that.